# New Server: What things to take care of when setting up a webserver to host multiple websites?

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, webserver

I am setting up my first webserver. On this machine, I want to run a couple of websites. Let xyz.com and abc.com and they will not be on seperate virtual machines. I have a few queries:

- What should be the configuration values for FQDN so that I don't face problems with both websites?
- I will be sending out customer emails from these 2 sites. Since both hosted on the same machine with a single IP, can a single PTR value cause problems with emails?
- In Postfix, there is `myhostname` which is typically set to the FQDN. If I prefer to setup only a single Postfix instance, how do I handle this `myhostname` when sending emails for both of these sites?

Are there any other things related to the setup that I need to take care of for proper functionality of both sites?

Answer (score 0):

About postfix:

You should fill up `/etc/hostname` according to `FQDN`.

for webserver, you should configure your webserver name-base apache that i preffer to read the manual such :[debian name-base apache](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.http-web-server.html)

Yes, you can , all of shared host, uses one ip and shared via apache or nginX, some of them define an `alias ip` in `/etc/hosts`

Comment: I know /etc/hostname reflects the FQDN. But my query was selecting the value of FQDN as I will be hosting 2 different websites and FQDN is only one and it's value is based on the single website it hosts.

Comment: i said FQDN just for mail, and i said name-base configuration for webserver.

Comment: If you want to configure a multiple domain mailserver, it's easy , you just need to read Virtual Domain.